How to explicitly set values to None in FastAPI with Pydantic models?
I'm using a Repository which updates values in db only if the value is not None.
db_entry = get_entry(...)
for name, value in entry_to_update.dict().items():
    setattr(db_entry, name, value) if value else None

But sometimes i want to reset a value explicit to None, which would be currently not possible.
I wonder what is the best approach to solve this?
I think a good approach would be to add a condition which checks if the value was explicit set to None else it would be not be part of the  entry_to_update.dict.
for name, value in entry_to_update.dict().items():
    if value is not None or (value is None and name in answer.dict()):
        setattr(db_entry, name, value)

But my Pydantic Schema always returns None values if created:
class EntryToUpdateSchema(BaseModel):
    value_a: Optional[str]
    value_b: Optional[str]

entry_to_update = EntryToUpdateSchema(value_a="A")
# entry_to_update is then EntryToUpdateSchema(value_a="A", value_b=None)
# -> value_b would be set to None but should be ignored

A other possible solution would be to update always every attribute from the entry, but i don't want that my frontend get all attributes.
Therefore i thought about to introduce a new Object, which indicates that the value was set explicit to None.
Something like:
for name, value in entry_to_update.dict().items():
    if value is not None or isinstance(value, ValueNoneObject):
        setattr(db_entry, name, None if isinstance(value, ValueNoneObject) else value)

But I think there must be a better or more common solution for that.

pydantic v2: entry_to_update.model_dump(exclude_unset=True), pydantic v1: entry_to_update.dict(exclude_unset=True)
